# Aggregate Exceptions in c# not saving individual exception messages

Tags: c#, exception

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
foreach (var setting in RequiredSettings)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!BankSettings.Contains(setting))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Setting " + setting + " is required.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        catExceptions.Add(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (catExceptions.Any())
            {
                throw new AggregateException(catExceptions);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            BankSettingExceptions.Add(e);
        }

        if (BankSettingExceptions.Any())
        {
            throw new AggregateException(BankSettingExceptions);
        }
```

catExceptions is a list of exceptions that I add to.  When the loop is done I then take that list and add them to the AggregateException then throw it.  When I run the debugger each of the string messages 'Setting X is required' appears in the catExceptions collection.  However, when it comes down to the AggregateException the only message is now 'One or more errors have occurred'.

Is there a way that I can aggregate while still keeping the individual messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can aggregate while still keeping the individual messages?

Yes.  The [InnerExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions.aspx) property will include all of the exceptions, with their messages.

You could display these as needed.  For example:

```
try
{
    SomethingBad();
}
catch(AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach(var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: +1 There are a number of ways to put the messages together. LINQ would, perhaps, make more sense if you are reporting this in a dialog.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Of course - I just did this to show where they are... Not suggesting it's the best option, by any means ;)

Answer (score 2):

The poster above has given the correct answer however rather than using a foreach loop one can use the `.handle()` method.

```
try
{
    SomethingBad();
}
catch(AggregateException ae)
{
    ae.handle(x => {
        Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
        return true;
    });
}
```